# Display Inline elements with word wrapping

Tags: css

I am trying to layout three divs inline next to each other. The last div could have a very long first word in its content, and when it does, it wraps to the next line. I want it to remain on the first line and wrap the word instead.

I have the following:

```css
#container {
  width: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#text1 {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

#text2 {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

#title-container {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  display: inline;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#title {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  -ms-word-wrap: break-word;
  -ms-word-break: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="text1">
    Text1
  </div>
  <div id="text2">
    12345
  </div>
  <div id="title-container">
    <span id="title">verryyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyrrrrrrrrrrryyyyyyyyyyyyyy long title</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a fiddle demonstrating the problem.

https://jsfiddle.net/wzm3h6u6/

What is the correct fix here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `word-break: break-all;` `css` to `#title-container`

```css
#container {
  width: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#text1 {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

#text2 {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

#title-container {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  display: inline;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  word-break: break-all;
}

#title {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  -ms-word-wrap: break-word;
  -ms-word-break: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="text1">
    Text1
  </div>
  <div id="text2">
    12345
  </div>
  <div id="title-container">
    <span id="title">verryyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyrrrrrrrrrrryyyyyyyyyyyyyy long title</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the issue!

Answer (score 1):

To do this you need to add a width to your #title-container div so it knows which width to stay at rather than it being determined by its contents.

word-wrap: break-word; to wrap the text.
display: inline-block;
And finally vertical-align: top to align with the top of the container.

```
#title-container {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

See fiddle [here](https://jsbin.com/mobucinubo/edit?output)

Comment: Fiddle link is a 404

Comment: Link fixed now.